# using chrome to access HTML files on android

Tags: html

I downloaded the java documentation to read on my phone but i can't use the html viewer on my phone because it cant use links.

When I tried using google chrome and going to the file location its not allowing chrome to access the location.

Does anyone know how to allow chrome to access the folder or know a folder that I could move the documents to?

[The documents I have.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/java-tutorial-downloads-2005894.html) It's the Zip file I'm using.
Before someone says I could use the epub or mobi, they are missing some of the bits i want to read.

Im using an HTC M9 and the location im trying to access is file:///download/tutorial/tutorial.

Thanks for any help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running Android 6 Marshmallow, you may need to grant Chrome access to your user storage. Secondly, the correct URL path should be `file:///sdcard/Download/tutorial/tutorial`.

Comment: thank you. :) can finally start reading about the sound API XD